# in UML transformation from conceptual class to implementation class

Tags: uml

In UML just going from conceptual class to an implemetation model. What sort of transformation does it implent? Are cardinalities the same? Are relationship the same? like: does composition remain the same? Wouldn't it be better to become a dependency relationship? cause composition higher coupling then dependancy. And  apparently we're looking for low-coupling.
I read all sort of little pieces here to there. Like bi-directionals [relationship are better becoming uni-directional according to](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/change-bidirectional-association-to-unidirectional) https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/change-bidirectional-association-to-unidirectional
etc
Is there not any "standards" ? or better reference on that matter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It surely depends on the type of transformation you want to do. The simplest case is a 1:1 transformation where you create a mere copy of your concept and develop that to some coding level. Usually the transformation will just leave traces backwards so you later know from where a concrete class was derived from. But you can also do specific transformations. Most common would be transformation to a data model. Here you would usually add primary keys and create foreign keys from associations. Another common transformation is one that targets a specific language and prepares constructs that convert compositions/multiplicities to arrays or the like.